# WndProc and Window events

Tags: c#, wpf, wndproc

I have a wpf application, i want to catch the events of window beginmove, window endmove, window beginresize, window endresize, and catch if user is move the window by mouse (begin and end), or change the location by keyboard (Window key + arrows keys)..

I find the list of window message - http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/WindowsMessages.html, but i'm not sure which relevant message are matched for me?

Comment: Start from [`WM_MOVING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632632.aspx). Keyword: WinAPI.

Comment: WM_MOVING = window begin move (by mouse), WM_MOVE = end move (by mouse and by keyboard), WM_SIZING = start resize, WM_SIZE=end resize.. thanks, now i should only the match event for start change kication by keyboard

Comment: Use the Spy++ utility included with Visual Studio.  It shows you a trace of all messages your window receives.